# Wordpress. Страница или плагин?

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Имеется простой PHP-скрипт, результат работы которого я хочу увидеть на отдельной странице сайта работающего под wordpress, добавив ссылку на эту страницу в меню (упрощенный образец кода ниже). Как я понимаю, "страницы", создаваемые в пользователем, могут содержать только статичный html, а плагины предназначены для добавления функционала к работе движка, но не для отдельных, обособленных выводов. Как мне лучше поступить?

```
<?php
$sqlLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'jKQsa821');
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `item_01`, `number` FROM database.items LIMIT 100;', $sqlLink);

$html = "";
$html.= "\n<table>\n<tr><th>Предмет</th><th>Количество</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $html.="\t<tr><td>" . $row['item_01'] . "</td><td>" . $row['number'] . "</td></tr>\n";
}
$html.='</table>';
print $html;
//Ну вот, примерно, как-то так =)
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

например вы можете воспользоваться шорткодами

```
function bartag_func( ) {
    //ваши действия-вычисления
    return "текст, который хотите вывести";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

добавив такой код в качестве плагина, и написав в своем сообщении

```
[bartag]
```

, вы соответсвенно в этом посте выполните этот скрипт

Вообще шорткоды имеют гораздо более широкое применение(умеют принимать параметры, и быть вложенными как HTML

подробнее
[Shortcode_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Так и сделаю.